# C++ Fallout new vegas directx hook and custom drawing

Tags: c++, directx

i wrote a directx hook for displaying custom things in Fallout NV,but i get a problem i can't understand.

Init code:

```
hdc=CreateCompatibleDC(NULL);
font=CreateFont(1000,0,0,0,FW_NORMAL,false,false,false,DEFAULT_CHARSET,OUT_DEFAULT_PRECIS,CLIP    _DEFAULT_PRECIS,DEFAULT_QUALITY,DEFAULT_PITCH|FF_DONTCARE,"Arial");
SelectObject(hdc, font);
D3DXCreateText(this->m_pIDirect3DDevice9,hdc,"Hello World",0.001f,0.4f,&mesh,NULL,NULL);
```

Code on EndScene Hook:

```
m_pIDirect3DDevice9->SetRenderState(D3DRS_CULLMODE, D3DCULL_NONE);
D3DXMATRIX world_matrix; //Pre-initialized
D3DXMatrixIdentity(&world_matrix);
D3DXMatrixTranslation(&world_matrix,-67762,3567,8384);
m_pIDirect3DDevice9->SetTransform(D3DTS_WORLD,&world_matrix);
mesh->DrawSubset(0);
```

This is the result:

[image]

As you can see the image is 2d (it should be 3d) and also it's like a "mask" of the scene, why?
What am i missing?

Comment: It is 3d. It's just in camera coordinates. Also, SetRenderState has like zilion settings, and you set only one of them (culling mode). Probably the device is left in some transparency mode after rendering UI. (D3DRS_ALPHABLENDENABLE maybe?)

Comment: Isn't the 0.4f the extrusion amount are you sure the extrusion amount is enough to be able to 'see' the 3Dness?? I'm guessing the font is in perspective and not parallel projection (i.e. you can walk round the text in the game - it's in worldspace?), though it looks like you are doing everything right - can't tell you why the mesh looks translucent - ah yeah didn't really think about the render state call as agent_l said :D

Comment: 99% last thing rendered was the UI. So rendering anything at this settings will give UI-like results.

Comment: @Charleh The text is "attached" to the screen, no matter what coords i put i always see it like that

Comment: So it looks like in the render pass you are translating the font mesh in relation to the camera coords - you need to reset the matrix in order to render to absolute coords, remember that a translation is additive - like agent_l said, probably last render pass before this was UI pass and you need to reset stuff (I don't do much DX so I wouldn't know what to call, but the API docs should give you some ideas).

Comment: @Charleh This is what i do calling D3DXMatrixIdentity before translating ;)

Comment: Ah yeah, see that now, like I said not much XP with DX - but still sounds like an additive camera coords issue, only other thing I can suggest is that your transform on D3DTS_WORLD is adding to a previous transform that's been applied, but I'm not sure how DX transforms work - will read up in the API docs though

Comment: Well only other thing I can suggest is that maybe world_matrix is not what you are expecting - since the code is so simple (reset/translate->apply to world), what is world_matrix expected to be, and what does it actually look like?

Comment: @Charleh The world matrix should only move the render to the position -67762,3567,8384 and render the text there.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11942/discussion-between-roberto-and-charleh)

Comment: @Agent_L I tried moving and rotating the text mesh, nothing.... also i tried activating z buffer and disabling blending, same result.